# How to use collections.js in typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to use [collections.js](http://www.collectionsjs.com/) in my typescript Angular2 project. I want to start with multimap. There's no `@types/collections` package and there's no collections.js in typings.

When I write

```
const MultiMap = require('collections/multi-map')
```

I got "NoProviderError for PlatformRef" in Agnular2.

Comment: Yes, that's where I started. @types/collections is not in the npm registry.

Comment: Do you also have a definition for `require` function somewhere?

Comment: No, I dont think so. I'm using https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter as a startet kit.

Comment: Yes, I can see that they include `"node"` typings in their `tsconfig.json`

Comment: I dont understand why I getting this NoProviderError in case i require "collections/multi-map"

Comment: The problem is with how `angular2-webpack-starter` handles Node.js dependencies. It looks like `multi-map.js` file import works, but it causes this weird `NoProviderError`. When I remove `var Map = require("./map").CollectionsMap;` line from `multi-map.js`, the error is gone. So the problem here is with recursive commonjs dependencies.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An error `NoProviderError` is caused by the fact that collection.js library changes the way how built-in primitives work, particularly `Array`.

Internally, `zone.js` (which is a part of Angular) invokes `Array.from` with an instance of `MapIterator` as an argument. In `collections/shim-array.js` file, this library overrides `Array.from` with an implementation, that doesn't work with `MapIterator`. In screenshot you can see, that it returns an empty array, while native implementation returns an array of 13 elements.

[image]

A conclusion is, that sadly you can't use Collections.js library with Angular.

Comment: Wrong. You can still use it. Just override Array.from after the library 'collections' is imported in the entry point.